# Calculus concept

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let's get straight to the point.
In my course we have section of calculus. So if we have a function which have vertical tangent(s). Can we evaluate it's antiderivative. As we were told derivatives DNE for discontinuity, LHD not equal RHD and vertical tangent. So will it be true?

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ has undefined derivative at $x=0$ but it has antiderivatives given by
$$\int f(x)dx=\frac{3}{5}x\sqrt[3]{x^2}+C$$